# Orthographic projection for South America in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, south-america

I would like to plot a map using an orthographic projection for South America in ArcMap. The goal is for the final map to look like this: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:South_America_(orthographic_projection).svg

However, I noticed I only have orthographic projections for the North and South poles in my ArcMap.

Is there another type of projection I could use for the same result or even a way to download the projection I need from some website and import it into ArcMap?

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like thanks within your posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to define a custom coordinate system.

Open data frame properties (right click the map or Layers in the table of contents and select properties) and select the Coordinate System tab.

Select South Pole Orthographic (in projected coordinate systems - polar folder).

Right-click it and select copy and modify.

Update the name and parameters of the projected coordinate system (PCS). OK the dialog and it will now be the selected PCS of the map.

If you want, you can right-click the name and select save as to save a copy (as a .prj file).

Comment: What EPSG number is "South Pole Orthographic"?

Comment: No EPSG number as it's Esri-specific: 102037. EPSG doesn't usually include small-scale projCRS unless a governmental agency or multiple other groups are using it.